# operator overloading with friend and member function

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

With in a class if we are using both member function and friend function to overload + operator its giving an error that ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’  how to resolve

Comment: Well which one do you want to call?

Comment: Remove one of them...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing it as a non-member function. That way, you can overload the function with other combinations. As an example, let's say you have a class `Point` and another class `Vector` (a gometric vector, not the `std::vector`).

You can overload

```
Point operator+(Point const&, Vector const&);
Point operator+(Vector const&, Point const&);
```

If you implement it as a member function, you implement only one of them in a class. To implement both, you'll have to implement the first one as a member function of `Point` and the second one as a member function of `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a member and non-member overload of `operator+`, if you really wanted to.

```
Foo a, b;
a.operator+(b); //call member function
operator+(a, b); //call non-member function
```

It ruins the whole point of operators, though, since you have to actually write out the method call.

---

Side note: non-member `operator+` doesn't need to be a friend function. It's easily written as:

```
Foo operator+ (Foo lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```